# In react native how to repeat same render n times using json data,please explain clearly without any hesitate

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, for-loop

here I am trying to repeat one view it contains image,icon,and some text using fab button on press with the help of json and for loop,if it is done it is going to execute or it will throw the errors,suggest best method to do this.

Comment: Please post your code and what did you try so far and what error you are receiving.

Comment: i did not start yet ,to see some examples to understand how it flows,thanks for your msg ,if you have any example code please share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the map function to repeat a component multiple times.

```
export default function AppExample({jsonList}) {

  const getCustomView = () => {
    return jsonList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <MyCostomView
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return (
      <View>
        {getCustomView()}
      </View>
  );
}
```

Here **jsonList** is an array of objects.
**MyCustomView** is another component that includes your image text, use key with some unique id like image URL (if any).

Comment: Rendering repeating component inside ScrollView using a map is not performance efficient as FlatList,

Answer (score 0):

use Flatlist for rendering view multitple times

```
 <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
```

where data can be your JSON data and renderItem Will be your View that you want to repeat.

For detail, example check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html)